# How to retry api request once the refreshtoken api is called?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, interceptor, refresh-token

Hi im using http interceptor in dart to handle refreshtoken,
How can i call the api request again once the refreshtoken api is called in using thee interceptor and got the new accesstoken.

```
   class ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy extends RetryPolicy {
   @override
   Future<bool> shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse(ResponseData response) async {
   if (response.statusCode == 401) {
   await GetFitbitAccessToken().getAccessToken();
   return true;
    }

   return false;
    }
   }


              ------------------------------------

Client client = InterceptedClient.build(
interceptors: [
  FitbitApiInterceptor(),
 ],

 retryPolicy: ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy(),
);
```

Comment: When you received the first bearer token,  you usually get expiary in it. you can use that time to see if the token is still valid, if the time has passed that means a new token needs to be fetched using the refresh token.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,i have done this  var token =
                                  (await sp.getFitbitAccessToken()) ?? "";
                              var dateTime = sp.getFitbitdateTime();
                              var duration = sp.getFitbitTokenExpiry();
                              if (DateTime.parse(dateTime!)
                                  .add(Duration(seconds: int.parse(duration!)))
                                  .isAfter(DateTime.now())) {
                                await GetFitbitAccessToken().getAccessToken();
                              }

Comment: can we do the same using interceptor

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need error 401(UnAuthorized) does not necessarily mean the token has expired so I believe you should have a refresh token to handle such cases. If your API has a refresh token then do this.

```
class ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy extends RetryPolicy {
   @override
   Future<bool> shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse(ResponseData response) async {
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // do your normal request
   return true;
    }else if(response.statusCode =401){
     //for POST
    ///within the header add this
     headers: {'grant_type': 'refresh_token', 'refresh_token': 
      '$refresh_token'});
      token = jsonDecode(response.body)['token'];
      refresh_token = jsonDecode(response.body)['refresh_token'];
      return true;
   }

   return false;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, in the  await GetFitbitAccessToken().getAccessToken(); method im calling the refresh token api and the new value will be stored in shared prefs

Comment: Ok cool! Are you certain the SharedPrefs works okay?? It would be good if you posted how `GetFitbitAccessToken().getAccessToken();` works just remove the sensitive info if possible

Comment: Future<int> getAccessToken() async {
 var uri = Uri.parse(         '${FitbitEnvironment.apiBaseURL}${Endpoints.fitbitAccessToken(fitbitRefreshToken!, '$token_expiry')}'); response = await http.post(uri, headers: headers);if (response.statusCode == 200) {
Map valueMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
var accesstoken = valueMap["access_token"];
sp.saveFitbitAccessToken(accesstoken.toString());
var refreshToken = valueMap["refresh_token"];
   sp.saveFitbitRefreshToken(refreshToken.toString());
 var expires_in = valueMap["expires_in"];  sp.saveFitbitTokenExpiry(expires_in.toString());
}